# Microsoft Azure WEB APPS - FTPS Passive Port Range

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm working with my AppDev team to get a few Web Apps setup up in Azure, formerly Azure Websites.  They would like to use the FTPS option to upload their code but we are running into our firewall when trying to connect over the FTPS passive ports.  I can get my Network team to get ports opened up but haven't been able to find what range MS uses.  Does anyone know where to find the passive port range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passiveportrange used for Azure Webapps is 10001-10300. Please configure your firewall and let me know if you run in to any issues.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: is that documented somewhere?